# Creating a document provider to integrate with Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am looking at wanting to create a custom document provider to integrate with Microsoft Teams.

I have looked through the code samples here but cannot find anything that would do this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/code-samples

Looking at this link, it quotes:

> You can always add more cloud storage from other services. Additional services and integrations are available under the “Apps” menu, which you can access by clicking the “Apps” icon in the bottom-left corner

This would suggest to me that you can build third party document providers, but without any documentation or examples I am stumped on how to do this.

https://www.howtogeek.com/661374/how-to-add-third-party-cloud-storage-in-microsoft-teams

Comment: Team supports Dropbox, ShareFiles, Google drive & Box as inbuilt storage. You can use sharepoint also apart from them it don't have any extended support for other cloud storage